# Right join query in symfony3 with doctrine

Tags: sql, join, doctrine-orm, symfony, right-join

I want to convert the sql query below to doctrine query in symfony.

```
select p.name,p.id,sum(t.amount) as bal from transactions t right join processors p on t.processor_id=p.id where user_id=18 or user_id is null group by p.id
```

The above code fetches balance from transactions table by summing up amounts of each transaction for a user for each processor.

## Result:

Processor1    ---------          43

Processor2    ---------      12

Processor3    ---------      NULL

Processor4    ---------      NULL

Processor5    ---------      NULL

The query i tried with dql is:

```
$sql = $procRepo->createQueryBuilder('t');
        $sql->select('p.name');
        $sql->leftJoin('t.processorId','p');
        $sql->addSelect('sum(t.amount) as bal');
        $sql->groupBy('p.id');
        $sql->orderBy('p.name')->getQuery()->getResult();
```

**Result:**

Processor1 --------- 43

Processor2 --------- 12

So my problem is i also want to get the NULL rows.

***Note: I am using Symfony 3***

Can anybody help?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You needs to invert the `join` statement to gets all processors:

```
$sql = $procRepo->createQueryBuilder('p');
$sql->select('p.name', 'sum(t.amount) as bal');
$sql->leftJoin('p.transaction', 't');
$sql->groupBy('p.id');
$result = $sql->orderBy('p.name')->getQuery()->getResult();
```

> This query must be made in your `ProcessorRepository`.

Comment: I got this when i did that.

`[Semantical Error] line 0, col 80 near 't GROUP BY p.id': Error: Class ModelBundle\Entity\Processor has no association named transaction`


Do i need to add any mapping info to processors entity

Comment: Yes, which is not the exact name of the relationship, please, fix that in your real code.

Comment: Actually i have two entities: Processor and Transaction<br />  
There is a manyToOne mapping for column "processor_id" in transaction.
Processor entity does not have any mapping to Transaction

Comment: well, test in you original query using `rightJoin` statement

Comment: it worked, just needed an inversedBy and mappedBy combo :)

Thanks so much!